# Reading csv table in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file that I am trying to read in R, for some reason R thinks the first row is the header for each column which is not true. Is there a way to get around this.
This is my command:

```
test <- as.matrix(read.csv(file="filetable.csv", sep=",", header=FALSE))
```

I get something like this

```
      AATCAGGC   X25070  
 [1,] "ACAAGGCT" " 50687"
 [2,] "ACACGATC" " 47483"
 [3,] "ACACTGAC" " 18339"
 [4,] "ACAGGAGT" " 48550"
```

the first row should be part of the data

Opening filetable.csv in notepad I get this

```
AATCAGGC,25070
ACAAGGCT,50687
ACACGATC,47483
ACACTGAC,18339
ACAGGAGT,48550
```

Thanks

Comment: I suspect there's either something wrong with your file or you're not looking at the resulting object from your `read.csv` call.

Comment: so I just run "test <- as.matrix(read.csv(file="filetable.csv", sep=",", header=FALSE))" followed by "test" and I get whats shown above

Comment: Open `filetable.csv` in notepad and post the contents in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's header=FALSE not head: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/read.table.html

```
> tempFile <- tempfile()
> writeLines(c("AATCAGGC,25070",
 "ACAAGGCT,50687",
 "ACACGATC,47483",
 "ACACTGAC,18339",
 "ACAGGAGT,48550"),tempFile,sep="\n")
> readLines(tempFile)
[1] "AATCAGGC,25070" "ACAAGGCT,50687" "ACACGATC,47483" "ACACTGAC,18339" "ACAGGAGT,48550"
> as.matrix(read.csv(tempFile,sep=",",header=FALSE))
     V1         V2     
[1,] "AATCAGGC" "25070"
[2,] "ACAAGGCT" "50687"
[3,] "ACACGATC" "47483"
[4,] "ACACTGAC" "18339"
[5,] "ACAGGAGT" "48550"
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesnt solve the problem since header=FALSE is the default anyways. I have just edited it in the question.

Comment: In read.table yes not in read.csv
`> read.csv
function (file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".", 
    fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...) 
read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
    dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
<bytecode: 0x101b1be08>
<environment: namespace:utils>`

Comment: I just tested the change, and the outcome did not change

Comment: `header=TRUE` is the default for `read.csv`.  `head=FALSE` will work because [arguments can be partial matches](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Argument-matching).

Comment: Yeah 2.14.1 is what I have too, but I just dont get the same result

Comment: Even if you simply copy paste my example? Maybe there is something funky with the linebreaks in your file. But I can't think of anything that would cause this sort of output though.

Comment: @JulioDiaz: are you testing this in a clean / new session?  Are you using someone's .Rprofile and/or is there an .Rprofile.site?

Comment: So I was creating filetable.csv using java and i was using a println() statement I changed that to print(value+"\n") and it works better but now I get an error "non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Comment: @JulioDiaz: you probably have to convert the value from a numeric/integer to a string.  You may also need to be careful about EOL differences between Windows/*nix, but Java may take care of that for you.